# Save partial in var in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to save a partial in a var, and after, i want to send that var like a json var to JS... well, the example better:

My controller (that I call with AJAX):

```
data = {
    created: 'ok',
    up: (params['up'] == 'true') ? 1 : 0,
    down: (params['down'] == 'true' && params['up'] == 'false') ? 1 : 0,
    html: render text: 'ratings/show', locals: {debate_id: params['debate_id'].to_i}
}
format.json { render json: data.to_json }
```

Then in my JS file i want only need to do `data.html`

And the error:

```
syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
...             html: render partial: 'ratings/show', locals: {deb...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i know the answer to this question. I need to assign this partial to a var before assign this to my hash and I need to use `view_context` for no redirect to view (I hope I have explained because my english is bad :().

```
html = view_context.render partial: 'show', locals: {debate_id: params['debate_id'].to_i}
data = {
    created: 'ok',
    up: (params['up'] == 'true') ? 1 : 0,
    down: (params['down'] == 'true' && params['up'] == 'false') ? 1 : 0,
    html: html
}
format.json { render json: data.to_json }
```